# Javascript Help For Chrome Console? Clicking All links website

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, web, console

this website wants me to click ALL the links on the page (there's about 2000).

This is the code for each link:

```
<a href="#" id="27426879" class="unfollow">UNFOLLOW</a>
```

the ID changes all the time depending on the link.

Is it possible to supply me the javascript code to write into the console of google chrome to click ALL the "a" tags with the class of "unfollow" at once? thanks :)

Comment: Inject jQuery then `$('a.unfollow[href="#"]').click();`

Answer (score 4):

How about?

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a.unfollow[href=#]");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    links[i].click();
}
```

Comment: @Robin: Well it has to have one if the href is just #, right?

Comment: @danronmoon, `href='#'` does not mean `JavaScript`.

Comment: It just added it there so no link will get clicked that actually is a link. (has an url)

Comment: Try disabling JS and see how much unsubscribing will get done.

Answer (score 3):

Sure is:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a.unfollow'), function (link){
    link.click();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EAFMf/)

You *could* do it using a plain `for` loop as well, but I just found it faster to do it this way.

Comment: Just a side note, it's better to use `Array.prototype.forEach.call` instead of `[].forEach.call` because `[]` creates an empty array in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I used chat room this code works easy: $('a.unfollow').click()

Comment: You may have to add that jQuery has to be available for this to work.

Comment: It worked because `jQuery` was included/available in the document. I suggest you to delete your answer and accept one right answer that worked for you.